# Iron Router throwing exception in onData

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I have seen a strange exception in the onData() function of a Route Controller in iron-router.  The exception only seems to occur after I make a change to a file which of course causes meteor to restart the app.  I've put up a sample in github that demonstrates the problem here: https://github.com/benmonro/iron-router-bug

If you add a person by clicking submit, then click on that person's name, everything will load fine.  However, if you then make a change to some js (say add a comment).  Meteor will reload and you'll get the exception in the 'onData()' method which is attempting to use a property of the data returned from the 'data()' function.

The exception is here:

```
> Exception in defer callback: TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of
> undefined
>     at RouteController.extend.onData (http://localhost:3000/irDataBug.js?8327f0bf1bedee2437ec14bc4509d8f7e85079ab:33:19)
>     at RouteController.runHooks (http://localhost:3000/packages/iron-router.js?e9fac8016598ea034d4f30de5f0d356a9a24b6c5:827:16)
>     at http://localhost:3000/packages/iron-router.js?e9fac8016598ea034d4f30de5f0d356a9a24b6c5:2137:16
>     at Utils.extend._run.withNoStopsAllowed (http://localhost:3000/packages/iron-router.js?e9fac8016598ea034d4f30de5f0d356a9a24b6c5:2098:21)
>     at _assign._compute (http://localhost:3000/packages/deps.js?4a82362ae66e863a1c1a8b0a5fec6f665e2038d1:228:38)
>     at new Deps.Computation (http://localhost:3000/packages/deps.js?4a82362ae66e863a1c1a8b0a5fec6f665e2038d1:160:10)
>     at Object._assign.autorun (http://localhost:3000/packages/deps.js?4a82362ae66e863a1c1a8b0a5fec6f665e2038d1:380:13)
>     at http://localhost:3000/packages/iron-router.js?e9fac8016598ea034d4f30de5f0d356a9a24b6c5:2134:12
>     at Utils.extend._run.withNoStopsAllowed (http://localhost:3000/packages/iron-router.js?e9fac8016598ea034d4f30de5f0d356a9a24b6c5:2098:21)
>     at _assign._compute (http://localhost:3000/packages/deps.js?4a82362ae66e863a1c1a8b0a5fec6f665e2038d1:228:38)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data isn't ready after the reload so you need to add a [guard](https://dweldon.silvrback.com/guards) or an early return to the callback. Here's a simple fix:

```js
onData: function() {
  var thePerson = Router.current().data();
  if (!thePerson)
    return;

  if (thePerson.name === "Fred") {
    console.log("it's fred");
  } else {
    console.log("it's not fred");
  }
}
```

Because the callback is reactive, it will rerun once `thePerson` is found. Alternative solutions could involve a `waitOn` callback and then checking for `this.ready()`.

Comment: I'm confused.  Why does it call 'onData' when there isn't any data?  If the data isn't ready then shouldn't it just wait or timeout instead of just returning null?

Comment: That's a good question. :) You may want to file an issue and/or start digging into the IR code to figure out why.